# Connection String for JDBC when adding failover groups on azure sql server

Tags: azure, spring-boot, jdbc, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a primary sql server1 **(server1.database.windows.net)** in region A with a single db("demo").

Then,I set up auto failover group for server 1 by creating a secondary server 2 **(server2.database.windows.net)** in region B for the same db.

When I tried to connect using *my-failover-group-name.database.windows.net* as the server URL from my springboot app, it does not let me connect.

Currently using the JDBC connection string:-

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<my-failover-group-name>:1433;database=demo;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;loginTimeout=30;applicationIntent=ReadWrite;
```

Am I doing something wrong ? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you mean neither of these can be connected? What's your JDK version? Have you checked firewall rule for your Azure SQL Database server?

Comment: @JosephXu, Yeah If I want to connect them using server1.database.windows.net or server2.database.windows.net, I am able to connect. But I need my jdbc url in such a way if server1 fails, it automatically redirects to server2. JDK version is 1.8.0_251.

Comment: I've made a test using jdbc to connect to a failover group, it works well. What's your error message shows?

Comment: @JosephXu, yeah looks like a firewall issue. Got it sorted. Now I am able to connect. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please checked firewall rule for your Azure SQL Database server.